Receive file contents in React front-end application
I am having an API endpoint in my NodeJS application. I am posting a filename to it to find the specific file in a folder. I am doing it like this:
const fileDirectory = 'C:/Sites/private-uploads';
try {
    // Extract filename from request parameters or query string
    const body = ctx.request.body; // Assuming filename is passed as a parameter in the route
    const filename = body.data.filename;

    // Check if the file exists
    const filePath = path.join(fileDirectory, filename);
    console.log(filePath);
    if (!fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
        ctx.status = 404;
        ctx.body = { error: 'File not found' };
        return;
    }

    // Read the file contents as raw binary data
    const fileContents = await fs.readFile(filePath, null); // Passing null as the encoding parameter
    const fileSizeKB = fileContents.length / 1024; // Convert bytes to kilobytes
    console.log('File size:', fileSizeKB.toFixed(2), 'KB');

    // Set appropriate headers
    ctx.set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream'); // Set Content-Type to indicate binary data
    ctx.set('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename="${filename}"`); // Set filename for download

    // Send the file contents as the response body
    ctx.body = fileContents;
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    ctx.status = 500;
    ctx.body = { error: 'Error retrieving file contents' };
}

When doing console.log of the filesize it shows the right filesize.
In my React application I receive the file like:
const getFile = async (filename) => {
        try {
            const response = await api.post('/api/get-file', {
                data: {
                    filename: filename
                }
            });
            if (response.data) {
                console.log(response.data);
                const blob = new Blob([response.data]);
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                const a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = url;
                a.download = filename;
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
                document.body.removeChild(a);
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

It returns me a file but its filesize is bigger and the file can't be opened.
Anybody seeing what I am doing wrong here?

Well, I recommend rechecking the server side code and make sure the naming matches because file size should not change when you're requesting it from the client side.

They are the same
